# Strip lines in SSRS for quarters

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am looking for a good practice on how to put strip lines for quarters in a chart which will divide the last years 4th quarter from the next year's first quarter in a 8 quarter report.

What I need to accomplish is something that won't automatically move the strip lines when the month but when the quarter changes it will be moved and in case the quarter changes to the 1st quarter in which case only one strip line will be needed.

For example, in November 2017 I used the following expressions in the interval properties - for the first strip line:

```
=13 - Month(Fields!sysDate.Value) + 0.5
```

and

```
=17 - Month(Fields!sysDate.Value) + 0.5
```

for the second strip line. It gave me the result as shown on the first image.
The error happens when the month changed to December (not depending on the quarter), the strip line went one step forward (second image).

These quarter reports will be automatically created every four months, and in this case the position of the strip lines can't be fixed and it should be completely automated. The `sysDate.Value`in the expression is a column which fetches the current date in a stored procedure. I am completely free to modify the stored procedures and expressions at will so any type of advice will be welcomed.

Img1 - Before the month changed

[image: Img1 - Before the month changed]

Img2 - After the month changed

[image: Img2 - After the month changed]

The next scenario will be when the month changes to January, when only one Strip line will be needed so that the second strip line won't be needed at all. How to accomplish that?